# Python, For loop, Python loops

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop, nonetype

I have mistakenly printed the shortcode in python jupyter notebook as below:

```
[print(i) for i in range(0,3)]
Output>
0
1
2
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

I can not understand why it is a printing list of None at the last?
Kindly explain to me about this.

Comment: `[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]` is the result of the list comprehension you have created.. `print(i)` is a function that returns `None`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Script returns unintended "None" after execution of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974901/python-script-returns-unintended-none-after-execution-of-a-function)

Answer (score 2):

You ran

> [print(i) for i in range(0, 10)]

which captured the `None` return value from [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), ten times.

To avoid this, consider running it without a list comprehension:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python REPL where you run the code, outputs the evaluated result of the code you gave it.

So:

if I give it a list comprehension like:

```
[i for i in range(0,3)]
```

even though I wont explicitly print it the python REPL will print the evaluated result as

```
[0,1,2]
```

Now you get confused because you use `print(i)` function with a list comprehension.

So `print(i)` prints the `i` but also its return value (which is `None`) is used to create the list through list comprehension:

```
[print(i) for i in range(0,3)]
```

so the output is the output of the `print(i)` PLUS the REPL output of the evaluated list which is a list of `None`'s

```
0
1
2
[None, None, None]
```

In other words you created a list of `None`'s but along the way you also printed some values. if you only want to loop over some values and print then (and NOT create a list) then do:

```
for i in range(0, 3): print(i)
```