# Reversed Sequence in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a reversed sequence in python and wrote this code:

```py
def reverse_seq(n):

    sorted([i for i in range(1, n+1)], reverse=True)
print(reverse_seq(6))
```

but it gives me `None`.

Comment: The `reverse_seq` function doesn't include a `return`

Comment: 1. You can use the builtin function `reversed`. 2. In this case there's no need to use `reversed`, just use `range(n+1, 1, -1)`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `list(reversed(n))`? Is this a learning exercise, or homework or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Script returns unintended "None" after execution of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974901/python-script-returns-unintended-none-after-execution-of-a-function)

Answer (score 2):

In some programming languages, the last expression in a function is implicitly the value it returns. But in python, you have to have a [`return` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return-stmt), or you get `None`.

```
def reverse_seq(n):
    return sorted([i for i in range(1, n+1)], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `range` function like so:

```py
def reverse_seq(n):
    return range(n + 1, 1, -1)
```

- use `list(range(n + 1, 1, -1))` if the output must be a list.

Comment: I like this answer, no need to sort a range you just made; you get that for free

Comment: also, I just timed this way compared to the sorted() method, and at low list sizes (about 10 items) this way is roughly 2x faster, but at list sizes of 1000 the this is more like 1000x faster.

Note: this is with the list(range(n + 1, 1, -1)), if you leave the list() off it gets even faster

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse_seq(n):
    return  sorted([i for i in range(1, n+1)], reverse=True)
print(reverse_seq(6))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>> [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Note: You have to use `return` to return the value from a function otherwise it'll return `None` as output.